# How to keep changing a Images every 5 seconds in Flutter?

Tags: asynchronous, flutter

State Variables :

```
var moviePhotos = [
"http://www.kiwithebeauty.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/BLACK-PANTHER-COLLAGE-KIWI-THE-BEAUTY-MOVIE-MARVEL-800x350.png",
"https://static-ssl.businessinsider.com/image/5a7085a97e7a35f10c8b479f-1000/blackpanthershuri.jpg",
"https://longreadsblog.files.wordpress.com/2018/02/black-panther.jpg?w=1680",
"https://uziiw38pmyg1ai60732c4011-wpengine.netdna-ssl.com/wp-content/dropzone/2018/02/black-panther.jpg",
"https://static2.srcdn.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/Black-Panther-Trailer-1.jpg?q=50&w=1000&h=500&fit=crop&dpr=1.5",
"https://cdn.guidingtech.com/imager/media/assets/BP-2_acdb3e4bb37d0e3bcc26c97591d3dd6b.jpg",
"https://cdn.guidingtech.com/imager/media/assets/BP-8_acdb3e4bb37d0e3bcc26c97591d3dd6b.jpg"
];
var bannerPosition = 0;
```

I want the below function to change the position  in the array every 5 seconds by incrementation bannerPosition so that a new image renders on the app

```
testing() async {
    while(true){
        await new Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds : 5));
            if (bannerPosition < moviePhotos.length){
                print("Banner Position Pre");
                print(bannerPosition);
                setState(() {
                    bannerPosition = bannerPosition + 1;
                });
                print("Banner Position Post");
                print(bannerPosition);                      
            }                   
            else{
                setState(() {
                    bannerPosition = 0;
                });                     
            }       
        }

}
```

The "Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds : 5))" does not occur in an orderly fashion when I execute this code and it results in image rendering issues.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I don't know what you mean by 'does not occur in an orderly fashion'. While just looking at that I'd think it would work, except that I seem to remember there being something weird about using await in a loop. It might keep looping around and creating more and more calls to the delayed....

Instead, use a [Timer](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/dart-async/Timer-class.html). That way it handles the looping. I'd also advise saving a reference to the timer and stopping it in your state's dispose() function.

Here's a code example:

```
class ImageRotater extends StatefulWidget {
  List<String> photos;

  ImageRotater(this.photos);

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => new ImageRotaterState();
}

class ImageRotaterState extends State<ImageRotater> {
  int _pos = 0;
  Timer _timer;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _timer = Timer.periodic(new Duration(seconds: 5), () {
      setState(() {
        _pos = (_pos + 1) % widget.photos.length;
      });
    });
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Image.network(
      widget.photos[_pos],
      gaplessPlayback: true,
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _timer.cancel();
    _timer = null;
    super.dispose();
  }
}
```

Note that there still might be some inconsistency the first time it goes through the photos because it is just loading them as it goes. The 'gaplessPlayback' flag should make the previous image stick around until the new one is fully loaded.

Comment: What I mean by  'does not occur in an orderly fashion' is that my loop inside my testing() function is not delayed uniformly by 5 seconds each time. Therefore my variable bannerPosition does not change every 5 seconds (rather it happens in a sort of random time span - between 2 - 6 seconds). Hence my images keep changing in a  sort of random time frame.

Could you help me with the function to ensure there is a periodic change in bannerPosition every 5 seconds?

Comment: Okay, well as I said the timer is the best tool for a periodic change. I've updated with a code example.

Comment: If the above code not working then plz use this.                                                                    const oneSec = const Duration(seconds: 5);
    _timer = new Timer.periodic(
      oneSec,
      (Timer timer) => setState(
        () {
          _pos = (_pos + 1);
          //
        },
      ),
    );

Comment: Great exampel @rmtmckenzie

Answer (score 6):

Improving on "rmtmckenzie" answer, you need to use Timer.periodic if you want to repeat this every 5 seconds. See below

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    _timer = Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 5), (Timer t) {
      setState(() {
        _pos = (_pos + 1) % widget.photos.length;
      });
    });
    super.initState();
  }
```