# How to make this kind of animation in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

[Video reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RuUI5.jpg)

please check the link above to see the animation.

The one in the video is made in Java, An imageView changing images using UniversalImageLoader in 2500 milliseconds interval with a Handler.

JavaCode:

```
int imgs[] = {R.drawable.efone, R.drawable.eftwo, R.drawable.efthree, R.drawable.effour, R.drawable.effive};

backgroundSlide = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.bgSlide);
backgroundSlide.setImageResource(R.drawable.efone);

final Handler handler = new Handler();
Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
    int i = 0;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        if (i > imgs.length - 1)
            i = 0;
        backgroundSlide.startAnimation(animAlpha);
        ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage("drawable://" + imgs[i], backgroundSlide);
        i++;
        handler.postDelayed(runnable, 2500);
    }
};
```

Xml:

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:id="@+id/bgSlide"
    android:src="@drawable/efone" />
```

Comment: I think this is all you need. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49444929/how-to-keep-changing-a-images-every-5-seconds-in-flutter)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to keep changing a Images every 5 seconds in Flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49444929/how-to-keep-changing-a-images-every-5-seconds-in-flutter)

Answer (score 2):

Giving you hint:

First add

```
import 'dart:async';
```

Suppose you have List of Images.

```
List<String> imgURLs = ['img1', img2, img3.....N];
```

Below code for change images:

```
int index = 0;
    const duration = const Duration(seconds:2); // change time as per your requirement 
    new Timer.periodic(duration, (timer){
      setState(){
        imageObj = imgURLs[index];
      }
      if(index >= imgURLs.lenght-1) {
        timer.cancel();
      }
      index++;
    });
```

Put this code at your place might be in `initState` method and use **`imageObj`** to set your image on the screen.

> **imageObj** might be *Image* type or whatever *type* based on your image list