# How to render child without parent when using setState?

Tags: flutter

How to make the code in this answer [How to keep changing a Images every 5 seconds in Flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49444929/how-to-keep-changing-a-images-every-5-seconds-in-flutter) to avoid parent rebuild together with child? I want only child do the setState.

I want the setState in Timer does not affect the parent.

I read about how to only rerender the child without parent in this link https://androidpedia.net/en/knowledge-base/51725031/flutter-setstate-of-child-widget-without-rebuilding-parent, but I got confused to implement into the code.

[My Objective is like on the image, please click on this link to see the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RoyUZ.png)

The blue circle is logo and the red circle is banner. I want them act like gif. But I cannot do the hardcode and put gif. Because I extract the image from web, like the answer in [How to keep changing a Images every 5 seconds in Flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49444929/how-to-keep-changing-a-images-every-5-seconds-in-flutter) did. Therefore, I need to use setState, unfortunately it render the whole apps. How to only rerender the images only?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this example. In that code i just changed the container color, just replace it with image on your code.

```
class Sample extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  print("Parent Widget rebuild");

    return SafeArea(
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Container(
            height: 50,
            width: 50,
            color: Colors.red,
          ),
          SizedBox(height: 20),
          ChangingColor(),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ChangingColor extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ChangingColorState createState() => _ChangingColorState();
}

class _ChangingColorState extends State<ChangingColor> {
  Timer _timer;
  Color _color;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _timer = Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 5), (Timer t) {
      setState(() {
        _color = Colors.primaries[Random().nextInt(Colors.primaries.length)];
      });
    });
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  print("Child Widget rebuild");

    return Container(
      height: 50,
      width: 50,
      color: _color,
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _timer.cancel();
    _timer = null;
    super.dispose();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just extract the part you want to change into a new Stateful Widget.

You can do this by selecting that portion and pressing ctrl shift r in vs code.