# How to change color with certain second on timer?

Tags: flutter

Objective : I want to have different timing duration for each color 
Blue = 2 seconds 
Red = 5 seconds 
Green = 1 seconds 
Yellow = 8 seconds

I got the code from here [How to render child without parent when using setState?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63717081/how-to-render-child-without-parent-when-using-setstate/63717545#63717545),

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:math';

void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false, home: Sample()));
}

class Sample extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  print("Parent Widget rebuild");

    return SafeArea(
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Container(
            height: 50,
            width: 50,
            color: Colors.red,
          ),
          SizedBox(height: 20),
          ChangingColor(),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ChangingColor extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ChangingColorState createState() => _ChangingColorState();
}

class _ChangingColorState extends State<ChangingColor> {
  Timer _timer;
   Color _color;
  List<Color> arrColors = [Colors.blue, Colors.red, Colors.green, Colors.yellow] ;
  int _pos =0;
  List<int> arrSeconds = [2,5,1,8]; //here I set array for seconds

  @override
  void initState() {
    for (var e in arrSeconds) { 
      _timer = Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: e), (Timer t) { //I want the array looping using different seconds
      print("seconds: $e");
      setState(() {
        _pos = (_pos + 1) % arrColors.length;
      });
    });}
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  print("Child Widget rebuild");

    return Container(
      height: 50,
      width: 50,
      color: arrColors[_pos],
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _timer.cancel();
    _timer = null;
    super.dispose();
  }
}
```

The problem is seems like the timer did not finish yet but the color keep changing. Should I use async?

Comment: You need to put switch case in which you can check timer value and set position for color array acccordingly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Please try this:*

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:math';

void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false, home: Sample()));
}

class Sample extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print("Parent Widget rebuild");

    return SafeArea(
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Container(
            height: 50,
            width: 50,
            color: Colors.red,
          ),
          SizedBox(height: 20),
          ChangingColor(),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ChangingColor extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ChangingColorState createState() => _ChangingColorState();
}

class _ChangingColorState extends State<ChangingColor> {
  Timer _timer;
  Color _color;
  List<Color> arrColors = [Colors.blue, Colors.red, Colors.green, Colors.yellow] ;
  int _pos =0;
  List<int> arrSeconds = [2,5,1,8]; //here I set array for seconds

  @override
  void initState() {


    super.initState();
    doSomething();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print("Child Widget rebuild");

    return Container(
      height: 50,
      width: 50,
      color: arrColors[_pos],
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _timer.cancel();
    _timer = null;
    super.dispose();
  }

  Future<void> doSomething() async {
    var second=0;
    var colorCount=1;
    var count=0;
    var totalList=[];
       for(var e in arrSeconds){
         count=count+e;
         totalList.add(count);
       }
       print(totalList);
      _timer = Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 1), (Timer t) {
        if(totalList[totalList.length-1]==second){



          _timer.cancel();

          setState(() {
            _pos=0;
          });
          doSomething();
        }else{
          if(totalList.contains(second)){
            setState(() {

              _pos =colorCount;
              colorCount++;
              print(second);
            });
          }
        }


        second++;
      });
  }



}
```

Comment: Thank you so much !!!!  It's works. It solved my problem.